# ES6 Proxy calling methods as properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-proxy

I have the following class that is utilizing a Proxy for getting properties and methods:

```
class User extends Model {

    static table = 'users';
    _attributes = {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Testing',
        lastName: 'Test'
    };

    constructor() {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: function(target, name) {
                // proxy getting code for functions and properties
            }
        });
    }

    client() {
        return this.hasOne(Client, 'clientID');
    }
}
```

Within the get method of the proxy, retrieving attributes is trivial. I just check for their existence within `_attributes`, and return the value, otherwise null.

```
if (target._attributes.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
    return target._attributes[name];
}

return null;
```

Then I can use it as:

```
const user = new User();
console.log(user.id); // returns 1
console.log(user.firstName); // returns "Testing"
```

Within the get method of proxy, I can also check if the property called was a function, and return the appropriate function as a result:

```
if (typeof target[name] === 'function') {
    const originalFunction = target[name];
    return function(...args) {
        return originalFunction.apply(this, args);
    };
}
```

Then I can use it as:

```
const user = new User();
user.client(); // Returns the return value of client() from the class
```

However, within the get function of the proxy, I am unable to differentiate between `user.client()` and `user.client`. In the first case, I want to return the result of the function. In the second case, I want to retrieve the result of the function, perform an additional step, and then return that.

In Pseudo-code:

```
if (property is a function call) {
    return property();
}
else if (property is a function, but not a function call) {
    return property().doSomethingElse();
}
```

Using a Proxy, can I tell the difference between `user.client()` and `user.client` from within the get method?

In PHP, this is possible using the magic methods `__get` vs `__call`, but I am looking for a way to do this in Javascript.

Comment: You shouldn't use proxies for anything. They're a misfeature. Getters and setters look like they would work fine here with the same interface, even.

Comment: @Ryan can you please elaborate on that? I'm not sure how with a getter I could call ```user.client``` and have it return the result of the function with an additional operation applied. Something like, if ```user.client()``` return just the function call, else if ```user.client``` return ```user.client().somethingElse()```

Comment: You can't make `user.client` take on different values depending on whether it's called.

Comment: @Ryan That is what I figured. Unfortunate really as other languages have support for this.

Comment: I don't think it's unfortunate at all – it would clash with programmer expectations about how expressions work. Providing a `user.client` getter and `user.foo('client')` method is more explicit.

Comment: @Ryan I just like that, for instance, in Laravel you can do this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships ```user->client``` would return the Model, whereas ```user->client()``` returns a query builder that you can work with ```user->client()->where(...```. But thanks for suggesting the getter vs method for clarification.

Comment: @Ryan "You shouldn't use proxies for anything. They're a misfeature." Hahah, that has to be one of the most absurd things I've ever read on StackOverflow. True, they are often horribly misused and don't work well on built-in objects, but they still offer enormous utility.

Comment: @ElliotB.: Everything you can do with a proxy is better done with a more explicit design.

Comment: @Ryan That's not true. What's "better" is entirely subjective.

Comment: @ElliotB.: Second sentence correct, first not. Anyway, feel free to do what you want.